# Updating values from different dataframe on a certain id value

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

`df1`

```
id      value       value_2
1       A           100
2       B           200
3       C           300
4       D           400
5       F           500
```

`df2`

```
id      value       value_2         many_irrelevant_collumns
1       nan         NaN             ...
2       B           200             ...
3       CCC         5000            ...
4       D           400             ...
5       FFF         50000           ...
```

I am trying to update columns `value & value_2` from `df1` to `df2` on `id` so that the result looks like this:

```
id      value       value_2         many_irrelevant_collumns
1       A           100             ...
2       B           200             ...
3       C           300             ...
4       D           400             ...
5       F           500             ...
```

I tried:

```
pd.merge(df1,  df2, how='left',on='id')
```

But this just adds the columns instead of updating the value. I am not sure if `pd.merge` is how this should be done.

Comment: I think solution with `update` is what need.

Comment: @jezrael, taking a look at it now